# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFF (С++)

Tags: c++, windows, ассемблер, x86-64

В Visual Studio 2019 через ассемблерную вставку, вызываю прерывание 10h. При запуске, ругается на нарушение доступа при чтении. Windows 10 x64. Игрался с параметрами исключений, не помогло. Прибегать к OpenGL очень не хочется.

Comment: Знаете, написал три варианта комментария, и все стер. Даже непонятно, как вам пояснить, что так это не работает. Просто примите на веру... А главное - зачем вам это? Чего вам не хватает в C++?

Comment: Ассемблерные вставки на платформе x86-64 вообще не поддерживаются. ¿И при чем тут OpenGL?

Comment: на старом компе с x32 Windows XP, пытался рисовать пиксели и линии на ассемблере, всё получалось. Решил написать программу для вывода графики, где вывод графики будет происходить средствами ассемблера, а логика на C++

Comment: Вы бы еще DOS вспомнили. Сейчас 2021 год, используйте DirectX11/12 или Direct2d.

Comment: Есть желание разобраться в работе с видеокартой на низком уровне, а не использовать что-то уже готовое

Comment: Ну тогда изучайте WDDM.

Comment: Спасибо. Начну копать в сторону WDDM

Comment: ох, и следующий вопрос будет "а как на wddm нарисовать пискель". Думаю, это деструктивное было предложение.

Comment: Нафига этот WDDM? Все известные мне приложения работают на Opengl,directx,vulkan.

Comment: Эх, хорошие были времена, когда пиксель выводился на экран одной лишь инструкцией mov, с помощью которой можно было написать Doom! Ушли безвозвратно.  Даже ring 0 из user mode захватить нельзя, как в 9x.

Answer (score 0):

Современные видео карты управляются своим процессором у которого своя память и свой ассемблер и на него ты не найдешь даже описания потому как это равнозначно описанию как ассемблер х86 преобразовывается в микрокоманды процессора.

Ты исходишь из предположения что видео карта и процессор разделяют общую память которая и отображается на экране, это в корне неверно уже давно, видео память находиться на плате видео карты и у процессора нет к ней прямого доступа.

Ты не сможешь прямо и непосредственно рисовать на ней даже если напишешь свою ось, для этого тебе придется написать свой "биос" для видео карты.